# How to avoid XSS attack

Tags: java, xss

If user enters javascript:alert(‘e’); in the comment section of my application, then on reloading the page it shows an alert . How to validate these kind of user inputs in java.

Comment: Start from this point [OWASP XSS cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: This question might be more suitable for http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use a built-in escaping mechanism like [<c:out>](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) or [<h:outputText>](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/outputText.html) to display your comments.

Answer (score 1):

A standard industry approach to remediate XSS attacks is to white list encode all inputs of your application. Make sure nothing out of predetermined input is allowed to come in. This is usually done with the use of regular expressions that scan all inputs.

Additionally to secure your application against reflected XSS attacks encoding output on the server side should be considered as well.

Have a look at the ESAPI and antisamy frameworks whitch provide API's to assist in this effort.

[Antisamy Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project)

[ESAPI Security API](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API)

Comment: I got it that i need to validate the input but how to do that. Do i need to place ESAPI jar inside my project.

Comment: Yes the jar needs to be in your classpath so you will be able to invoke the ESAPI API

Answer (score 0):

Every time you write a user input back to new page, the simplest approach is to escape the content.